# UIImage not updating on setImage on button IBAction

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, uibutton

So I am changing the Image of a button and the Image of a UIImageView using these two functions:

```
- (IBAction)changeButton:(id)sender {


    //switch image to group if it is a badge. switch image to badge if it is a group.

    if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"badge"]){
        NSLog(@"reaching badge");
        UIImage *imageToSet = [UIImage imageNamed:current_group_image];
        [changeButtonOutlet.imageView setImage:imageToSet];
        [properties setObject:@"group" forKey:@"current_item"];
    } else {
        if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"group"]){
            NSLog(@"reaching group");
            UIImage *imageToSet = [UIImage imageNamed:current_badge_image];
            [changeButtonOutlet.imageView setImage:imageToSet];         
            [properties setObject:@"badge" forKey:@"current_item"];

        } 
    }

    [self switchBadgeImage];
}

-(void)switchBadgeImage{
    if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"badge"]){
        [badgeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:current_badge_image ]];
    } else {
    if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"group"]){
        [badgeImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:current_group_image ]];    
    }
    }

}
```

However the images dont update. If I spam the changeButton IBAction I can sometimes very quickly see the images changing but it always flicks back to the default one (just for the button).

Here is what my console log tells me when I press the button repeatedly:

```
2012-08-24 12:20:52.414 MyApp[1448:707] reaching group
2012-08-24 12:20:52.559 MyApp[1448:707] reaching badge
2012-08-24 12:20:52.687 MyApp[1448:707] reaching group
2012-08-24 12:20:52.846 MyApp[1448:707] reaching badge
2012-08-24 12:20:52.976 MyApp[1448:707] reaching group
2012-08-24 12:20:53.117 MyApp[1448:707] reaching badge
2012-08-24 12:20:53.262 MyApp[1448:707] reaching group
2012-08-24 12:20:53.348 MyApp[1448:707] reaching badge
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks guys!

---

EDIT: FIXED IT! Here is the updated code:

-(void)switchBadgeImage{
    NSLog(@"current group image: %@", current_group_image);
    NSLog(@"current badge image: %@", current_badge_image);

```
current_item = [properties objectForKey:@"current_item"];

if([current_item isEqualToString:@"badge"]){
    NSLog(@"current item is equal to badge");
    [badgeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:current_badge_image ]];
} else {
    if([current_item isEqualToString:@"group"]){
         NSLog(@"current item is equal to group");
        [badgeImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:current_group_image ]];    
    }
}
```

}

```
- (IBAction)changeButton:(id)sender {

    //switch image to group if it is a badge. switch image to badge if it is a group.

    if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"badge"]){
        NSLog(@"reaching badge");
        UIImage *imageToSet = [UIImage imageNamed:current_badge_image];
        [changeButtonOutlet setImage:imageToSet forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [properties setObject:@"group" forKey:@"current_item"];
        [properties synchronize];
    } else {
        if([[properties objectForKey:@"current_item"] isEqualToString:@"group"]){
            NSLog(@"reaching group");
            UIImage *imageToSet = [UIImage imageNamed:current_group_image];
            [changeButtonOutlet setImage:imageToSet forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [properties setObject:@"badge" forKey:@"current_item"];
            [properties synchronize];
        } 
    }

    [self switchBadgeImage];


}
```

There was a few problems actually. first I was switching the images the wrong way around. Secondly I was not synchronising the UserDefaults. I was also not updating the current_item variable after saving the current item to the UserDefaults.

Thanks for all the help and so quickly!

Comment: Where is "current_badge_image" defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"];
[changeButtonOutlet setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Try this and as i know you need to set the State for that button. This code will set the Image and its not and background.let me know if any other thing is there.

Comment: I updated my question with the answer now. it was actually 2 or 3 things causing it not to work correctly. All is explained there. Thankyou for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To set an image for an `UIButton`, you must specify the `UIControlState` for which it will be used. The `imageView` property is not for setting a background image but to [`configure the appearance and behavior of the button’s view`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html).

The correct way to set an image is

```
[changeButtonOutlet setImage:imageToSet forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Different control states and their applications are listed [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIControlState).

Comment: ok so what about the UIImageView? This one is not a button so.

Comment: Are you sure your `current_badge_image` and `current_group_image` objects are valid?

Comment: yes the current_badge_image and current_group_image are entirely populated.

Comment: For what event do you call `changeButton:`? `UIControlEventTouchUpInside` or something else?

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside But I have fixed it now... updating my post with the fix and Upping your answers :) thanks guys :3. really appreciated.